# Array adapter versus Base adapter

Tags: java, android, arrays

I currently have four arrays with me that need to populate various elements in a custom layout list cell.
I've looked at Base Adapters and Array Adapters. The latter requiring the input data to be an ArrayList of Objects.

From a performance standpoint, would it be better to use a Base Adapter, or converting the current set of data into an ArrayList of objects, thus using more memory would be the option to use?

Comment: Hmm... simpler objects are better but sometimes they are usefull and more problematic. So there is possibility to customazine objects in your adapter. Everythink depends for what and what you would like to use that adapter. Sometimes there is better to go on compromiss with performance when your data are not quite big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with `BaseAdapter`. Removing the requirement that you use an `ArrayList` makes the implementation more flexible. The only additional work you have to do is implement a few basic methods like getCount() - which is most likely the length of your collection - or getObject() - which is probably the object at whatever position you're at in the list. You may even need to implement your own constructor but hey that's just part of using OOP. Not a big deal.

There's no performance difference from using one adapter over the other. `BaseAdapter` is the super class for multiple different adapter types (`ArrayAdapter` being one of them). If there's no cost, it makes no sense not to go with `BaseAdapter` You will get exactly the same result with more flexibility down the line.

Comment: why not go with ArrayAdapter? can you explain that too? I mean what is limitation in ArrayAdapter?

Comment: @UnKnown There's nothing wrong with an ArrayAdapter if you know you're going to be using a single ArrayList. You can't use an ArrayAdapter if the data you're trying to display isn't stored in that format. That happens a lot at least for me. So I just make a BaseAdapter that fits my needs.

Comment: but what If I override getView method of ArrayAdapter?

Comment: You have to override getView in all adapters to make it display what you want. You're just limited in certain types as to what collection you can use to hold your model objects backing the list.

Comment: I don't think so, because BaseAdapter also required to override getView(); then Really didn't understand what is the problem with ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the data when you create the Adapter, I'd advise going with the ArrayAdapter. It's less code, so less room for error. If you want to populate items on-the-fly, or your dataset might change significantly, maybe you'll want that extra control from your own Adapter.